# View Model Attributes Only If a Certain Condition is Met

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel with properties that have several DataAnnotations attributes, including `[Required]`, a custom validator that I wrote, and a `RegularExpression` attribute. Given a certain condition that will be set on the ViewModel, how can I make it so that it only runs the set attribute validators when that condition is true? I'm already using [RequiredIf](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/) but that only works for the `[Required]` attribute.

Example:

```
[RequiredIf("MyCondition", true, ErrorMessage="BlahBlah")]
[RegularExpression("MY_REGULAR_EXPRESSION")]
[CustomValidator]
public string MyString { get; set; }
```

Comment: Maybe don't use an attribute and implement IValidatableObject on your class?  This gives more flexibility than attributes.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this problem by passing the condition through the url and overriding the `AuthroizeCore` to parse the url for a specific variable name.

You can set a route (attribute routing here but I'm sure using a route dictionary will work similarly) like this:

```
<SecureRoleByItemIDAttribute>
<Route("ViewDetails/MoveItem/{itemID:int}/{itemType}")>
```

Notice the `itemType`

Then in your `AuthorizeCore` override:

```
Public Class SecureRoleByItemIDAttribute
    Inherits AuthorizeAttribute

    Protected Overrides Function AuthorizeCore(httpContext As HttpContextBase) As Boolean
        Dim isAuthorized As Boolean = False

            Dim itemTypeID = CType(httpContext.CurrentHandler, System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler).RequestContext.RouteData.Values.Item("itemType")

            'set boolean logic here

        Return isAuthorized
    End Function
End Class
```

The line containing `Dim itemTypeID` and the logic that follows is the meat and potatoes.  It searches the url for the value associated with '`itemType`' and then you can set your return boolean based on that.

I'm not sure if this helps in your specific situation, but there are a lot of neat things that can be done using this.